# Trying to make a simple program (in C) that copies all non empty lines from a given text file into a new text file

Tags: c, string, text, stdio

This is what I tried doing (if the first charcacter of a line is `'\n'` it must necessarily be an empty line) but it gives me the error message: `"Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x68"` at the line of `fgets`..

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAX_LEN 80

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fin,*fout;
    fin=fopen("poem_in.txt","r");
    fout=fopen("poem_out.txt","w");
    char line[MAX_LEN];

    do {
        fgets(line, MAX_LEN, fin);
        if ((line[0])!='\n') fputs(line,fout);
    } while(fgets(line, MAX_LEN, fin)!=NULL);

    fclose(fin);
    fclose(fout);
    return 0;
}
```

I tried looking at the correction my professor gave but she used `strcmp(line,"\n")` so its not very useful and I don't get how its possible to compare a string and a char? Any help at all would be greatly appreciated and would be of great help in my studies!

Comment: `"\n"` is not a char, it's a single-character string.

Comment: `while (fgets(...)) { ... }`: do not repeat the `fgets()` call

Comment: @pmg what do you mean? Why would it not repeat the call?

Comment: @Jonnyboy23 see Barmar's answer. You are currently reading 2 lines in each iteration, one in the first `fgets` call and the other one in the `fgets` call in the condition of the `while`.

Comment: `0 == strcmp(line, "\n")` is equivalent to `line[0] == '\n' && line[1] == '\0'`. But since fgets() will never return a string with characters after the newline, your test is equivalent, and simpler, and quicker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `fgets()` twice each time through the loop. As a result, you only check every other line for being empty.

Do it like this instead.

```
while (fgets(line, MAX_LEN, fin)) {
    if ((line[0])!='\n') fputs(line,fout);
}
```

If you're getting an error on the `fgets()` line, it's probably because the file wasn't opened successfully. You should check it first.

```
    fin=fopen("poem_in.txt","r");
    if (!fin) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open put file poem_in.txt\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    fout=fopen("poem_out.txt","w");
    if (!fout) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open output file poem_out.txt\n");
        exit(1);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i didn't even realise this was going on! So just to make sure, every time you put a function in the condition for the loop it is effectively being called again (and thus advancing the position indicator in this case?)

Comment: yes, every time you write a function call, it calls the function. Using it in `while` doesn't change that -- it doesn't mean to use the value from the previous call.

Comment: I have now fixed the code but it is still giving me the same error message.. any reason for this?

Comment: Sounds like it's getting an error trying to open the file. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! it works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried looking at the correction my professor gave but she used strcmp(line,"\n") so its not very useful and i don't get how its possible to compare a string and a char?

Actually "\n" is not a char but a C string. Note that the char would be written as **'\n'** and here you have C string (**"\n"**) and so it is possible to compare. Furthermore, you might want to take a look at the strcmp documentation http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/

Remember, however, that strcmp would read strings from arguments for as long as the NULL character is not found meaning that a bad formatted input would make it read more than intended which could lead to crashes. In order to prevent there is a smarter equivalent of strcmp called **strncpy** which takes an additional parameter - the maximum length of the input. You have this defined with MAX_LEN ans so if you decide to follow the suggestion of your professor it is better to use strncmp http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncmp/

> This is what I tried doing (if the first charcacter of a line is '\n' it must necessarily be an empty line) but it gives me the error message: "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x68" at the line of fgets..

Now, reading through your code there are a places that require your attention. For example you call fgets twice in the do-while loop:

```
do {
    fgets(line, MAX_LEN, fin);
    if ((line[0])!='\n') fputs(line,fout);
} while(fgets(line, MAX_LEN, fin)!=NULL);
```

You read a line from the file, and possibly write it to the another file. Then (inside the while) you read a line again but this time you do not look at it at all but instead do another read. Effectively you are skipping every 2nd line.

I think what you should do is start off with **while** loop instead of do-while and do the fgets in the while clausule. Then use strncmp to compare the output with a new-line character and save to the file the way you do it now. Something like:

```
while(fgets(...)) {
   if strncmp {
     fputs()
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the very in-depth answer! Her use of strcmp makes a lot more sense now!